# Where to view election litigation status

Tags: united-states, election, data-sources

Is there a way to view aggregated data for the litigations related to the recent federal elections in the US? I’m looking for a who/what/why status of each piece of litigation so I don’t have to check several separate data sources.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Wikipedia seems to have a nice list:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lawsuits_related_to_the_2020_United_States_presidential_election

SCOTUSblog has a 2020 Election Litigation Tracker:

https://www.scotusblog.com/election-litigation/

Brennan Center has a Voting Rights Litigation 2020 list:

https://www.brennancenter.org/our-work/court-cases/voting-rights-litigation-2020

Democracy Docket also has a list of election cases:

https://www.democracydocket.com/case_type/active-cases/

Comment: Maybe this should be another Question: Is there any analysis of which litigations are likely to change Electoral College votes?